# preg_grep on a larger string

Tags: php, regex, grep, pcre

I need to use preg_reg on some string with content from a html file.

```
$file = file_get_contents($path);
$html_array = explode(' ', $file);
```

The problem is that the array looks sometimes like this:

```
[77]=>
    string(35) "&lt;div>
&lt;/div>
&lt;br>
{{testto}}
&lt;br>"
```

I have tried to put in some whitespaces there.. :P Won't work.. :/ Later on I will do a preg_grep like this:

```
$childframes = preg_grep('!\{\{(\w+)\}\}!', $html_array);
$retur = array();
foreach($childframes as $v){
   $v = trim($v);
   $retur[] = substr($v, 2, -2);
}
return $retur;
```

So the idea is basically to get `{{testto}}` in a array, every occurrence of `{{sometext}}` where I substring it down to only 'sometext'.

Thanks =)

**EDIT:**

To repeat the problem: explode is not working right so I need some regex if possible, instead of just whitespace.., and is there any better way to do preg_grep on on a large string?

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do? guuranteed there's an easier way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to explode, create a temporary array, grep it and strip it later, just a regexp match:

```
$html = file_get_contents($path);
preg_match_all('#{{(.*?)}}#', $html, $matches);
$array_of_texts = $matches[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't you just want to use:

```
strip_tags($v)
```

first so that you are removing all of the html tags, then your code will get the 'sometext' correctly.